# Sourced git alias fails

Tags: git, bash

I have setup a custom git alias to make a pretty git log like this in my `~/.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
   l = "!source ~/.githelpers && git_pretty_log"
```

My `~/.githelpers` file contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

HASH="%C(yellow)%h%C(reset)"
RELATIVE_TIME="%C(green)%ar%C(reset)"
AUTHOR="%C(bold blue)%an%C(reset)"
REFS="%C(red)%d%C(reset)"
SUBJECT="%s"

FORMAT="$HASH{$RELATIVE_TIME{$AUTHOR{$REFS $SUBJECT"

function git_pretty_log() {
    git log --graph --pretty="tformat:$FORMAT" $* |
    column -t -s '{' |
    less -FXRS
}
```

But when I do `git l` in any repo I have I get:

```
$ git l
source ~/.githelpers && git_pretty_log: 1: source ~/.githelpers && git_pretty_log: source: not found
fatal: While expanding alias 'l': 'source ~/.githelpers && git_pretty_log': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does “Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type” mean?

Comment: @poke: No file or folder of this type.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `git_pretty_log` with `echo hello`?

Comment: Why not source `.githelpers` once from your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`? Then any functions defined there are available in any shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error seems to be that `source` is not an external binary, but instead a bash builtin.

```
$ git config alias.foo '!source .gitfoo'
$ git foo
source .gitfoo: 1: source .gitfoo: source: not found
```

Wrapping all this with a `bash -c` solves the problem.

```
$ git config alias.foo '!'"bash -c 'source .gitfoo && gitfoobar'"
$ echo 'function gitfoobar() { echo foo bar; }' >.gitfoo
$ git foo
foo bar
```

For your case:

```
git config --global alias.l '!'"bash -c 'source ~/.githelpers && git_pretty_log'"
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the quotation marks; it should just be:

```
[alias]
    l = !source ~/.githelpers && git_pretty_log
```

Otherwise, you're trying to run one long command that doesn't exist, just as the error message told you.